# replace `define with let construct

Tags: system-verilog, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to avoid using `define pre-processor and start using "let" since it's a language construct.

Here is my example:

```
`define MY_REGISTER_RANGE 15:0

logic [`MY_REGISTER_RANGE] my_array;
```

How can I do the same with let construct? My code is very simple but it assumes that I'm `include the file where my macro MY_REGISTER_RANGE is defined (in another file).

Thanks.

Comment: Beware also that `let` is not always synthesizable and you might get errors such as `Unsupported SV constructs 'let declaration' found during Elaboration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you do not need the `let` construct. Moreover, the construct has nothing to do with declarations of variables.

You can start using parameters instead of text macros. For example

```
parameter MY_REGISTER_WIDTH = 16;
...
logic [MY_REGISTER_WIDTH-1:0] my_array;
```

The `let` construct defines a simple function containing a single expression. In this respect it could be used to replace certain types of macros, e.g.

```
`define MULT(A,B)   A * B
...
R = `MULT(O1,O2);
```

could be replaced with

```
let MULT(A,B) = A * B;
...
R = MULT(O1,O2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only substitute certain kinds of expressions using `let`. You can't just define a range.

You should use a `typedef` instead of `let`

```
typedef logic [15:0] MY_REGISTER_t;
MY_REGISTER_t my_array;
```